# Set PowerPoint presentation when already opened (From Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to open a specific powerpoint slide decided by the user in Excel. The code to open the Powerpoint to the specific slide is the following (targ is a string like `"Slide:12"`):

```
Function rcFollowSlide(targ As String)
    Dim PptPath As String
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

    targ = Mid(targ, InStr(targ, ":") + 1)
    targ = Left(targ, Len(targ) - 1)
    PptPath = wsSettings.Range("PPTPath").Value

    If IsPPTOpen(PptPath) Then
        MsgBox "Already opened"
        Exit Function
        'Set ppres =
    Else
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(PptPath)
    End If

    If targ > 0 And targ <= pptPres.Slides.Count Then
        pptPres.Slides(CInt(targ)).Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Image " & targ & " N/A."
    End If
End Function
```

It works very well when the presentation is closed and it has to open it up. I'd like to set the Powerpoint presentation to pptPres when it's already opened as well, so I could get the code to continue running without opening a new instance of that presentation. How can I access the application in the first place, and set the presentation?

For reference, here is the function used to check if the PPT is already opened.

```
Function IsPPTOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsPPTOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsPPTOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Try: `Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations(Dir(PptPath))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
If IsPPTOpen(PptPath) Then
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations(Dir(PptPath))
    'Set ppres =
    Exit Function
Else
```

If you need to activate the presentation, try:

```
VBA.AppActivate (Dir(PptPath))
```

As you've noted, this may also work in some cases (see Thierry comment below).

```
PPTApp.Activate
PPTPres.Activate
```

Comment: AH I Googled it myself and saw that I could activate it with `pptApp.Activate`, didn't mean to be a help vampire :) Also I'll accept your answer when I can but for the sake of mentioning it, I moved the `Set pptApp` before the If condition of course.

Comment: PPTApp.Activate with activate PowerPoint but if the file was already open and they are many ppt files opened, the PptPath presentation may not be the Active Presentation. I like to use AppActivate (pptPres.Name).

Comment: good point @ThierryDalon `AppActivate` is a good one because it goes by the window name. OP could also do `pptPres.Activate` to activate the specific named presentation.

Comment: pptPres.Activate may not put the PPT App into focus (it sets pptPres as Active Presentation) but PPTApp.Activate will put PowerPoint into focus. (from my experience)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly different code:

*ppProgram* is `PowerPoint.Application`

*ppPres* is `PowerPoint.Presentation`

*ppFullPath* is the full path (Path & File Name)

*ppName* is the "clean" Name of the requested Presentation

```
' more than 1 Presentstion open
If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
    ppName = Mid(ppFullPath, InStrRev(ppFullPath, "\") + 1, Len(ppFullPath))
    i = 1
    Do Until i = ppProgram.Presentations.Count + 1
        If ppProgram.Presentations.Item(i).Name = ppName Then
            Set ppPres = ppProgram.Presentations.Item(i)
            GoTo OnePager_Pres_Found
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End If

OnePager_Pres_Found:
ppPres.Windows(1).Activate  ' activate the Presentation in case you have several open
```

Comment: Would this work if there was more than 1 Powerpoint application open at the same time? For example if you put powerpoint in the task bar and Middle-click on it with the mouse button.

Comment: PowerPoint only allows one instance of itself, so in general you don't have to worry about more than one PPT application open at once (unlike Excel and Word).